# Try and Catch not working on SQL open command

Tags: asp.net, sql, try-catch

I would like to initiate my page by checking authentication using SQL Database connection.  This is the code I have, and I can't figure out why it's not working:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Try to open database.
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blahblah"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        con.Close();
        //successful login, do nothing.
    }
    catch (Exception err) //if error Opening, catch the error, and display
    {
        SiteMasterMsg.Text = "Could not login in using ___.";
        SiteMasterMsg.Text += err.Message;
    }
```

The problem is the page just dies, and gives me the default IIS error page showing the database connection login failed.  My hope was that it would "try" to connect, and then on a failed login attempt, catch the error, and display the page with the error.  I have this on my Default.aspx page:

```
<asp:Label id="SiteMasterMsg" runat="server" />
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.  Am I missing something, or is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your connection string? (replace the password with dummy text)

Comment: Why would the generic error page come up? You're catching all exceptions. Are you sure the error comes from this code?

Comment: @DourHighArch that's how i've been checking: by using a good password, and purposely bad password, which causes successful or unsuccessful login, and DB connection.

Comment: Can you step through the code using a debugger and make sure this is actually where it's crashing?  @usr is on the right track here, that code you've shown wouldn't be showing you the generic error page.

Comment: @usr, the error is coming from the con.Open(); line inside of the try.  I'm baffled as to why it's not just 'trying' the con.Open(), and on fail 'catching' the error.

Comment: @jadarnel27, yes, i've printed response.write above and below the con.Open(); command, and the code stops a con.Open(); and doesn't continue, but prints the IIS error page.

Comment: This can't be the whole story. Maybe a 2nd exception is occurring after the first. Set VS to break on *all* exceptions. Also, anaylze the error page - it tells you exactly where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your help, further investigation and I think it's from the fact this is in my Site.Master.cs page.  My goal was to have this run on every page (inefficient i know - there aren't that many pages), but it might be possible it's dying when trying to present the page with the error code on it.  Is there a better way to do this? (authentication using sql authentication) Thanks again all!

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense.  Perhaps just place that label on your MasterPage as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem was because this code was on my Site.Master.cs page, so the page would never really fully develop, it would stop at some level of error, and that's what I was seeing.  The solution has been to make a  dedicated Login.aspx page, and not to put this code in the Site.Master.cs page.